# How to get the current day and last day of the current month

Tags: php, html

I'm just a beginner !! I need a html number input, with today's day of the month as the minimum value and number of day's of the current month as the maximum value.

In PHP I declare `$today = date ('Y-m-d,time());` to read the date today  and i don't know how to declare the value of the day of the month in `<Input type="number" min="" max="" />` as a minimum number?

Comment: there are a number of definitions for "current day"... day of the week? day of the month? day of the year? day since epoch? which one are you after?

Comment: Date type is not a number. You can extract number from it but it's not

Comment: this makes no sense. "Today" would be "4th July 2017". So then you have a "number" input box. What number corresponds to that date? Do you simply want 4 from it (in that example)? It's not clear.

Comment: Mr. Tmothy Groote .. I want an HTML input that represents a day of the month and set it as the minimum value to be today.

Comment: Come on guy's, the context seems logical what he wants. It seems people are very grumpy here about questions. Next time help people with their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Input type="number" min="<?= date('d') ?>" max="<?= date('t') ?>" />
```

I think this one help you...

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you need a html input that represents a day of the month. And you want the minimum value to be today.

If so:

You can format your date and use that as value.

```
$today = new DateTime();
// Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
$day_today; = $today->format('d');
// OR
//  Day of the month without leading zeros
$day_today; = $today->format('J');

//  Last day of the given month in datetime 
$last_day; = $today->format('t');

Choose day:<input type="number" min="<?php echo $day_today; ?>" max="<?php echo $last_day; ?>" />
```

Comment: thank you!!! it works!! and thank you for understanding my question hahaha!

Comment: but what if I want an HTML input that represents the last day of the month. And set it as maximum value to be today :)

Comment: I will add that one too ;) It's the "t" format. see http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php